# BigDecimal Subtraction

Tags: java, bigdecimal

I want to substract 2 `double` values, and I have tried the following code.

```
double val1 = 2.0;
double val2 = 1.10;

System.out.println(val1 - val2);
```

and I got the output as,

```
0.8999999999999999
```

For getting output as `0.9` I tried with `BigDecimal` as follows,

```
BigDecimal val1BD = new BigDecimal(val1);
BigDecimal val2BD = new BigDecimal(val2);

System.out.println(val1BD.subtract(val2BD));
```

And I got the output as,

```
0.899999999999999911182158029987476766109466552734375
```

Then I tried with `BigDecimal.valueOf()`

```
val1BD = BigDecimal.valueOf(val1);
val2BD = BigDecimal.valueOf(val2);

System.out.println(val1BD.subtract(val2BD));
```

And finally I got the output as `0.9`.

My question is what is the difference between case 2 & case 3?

In case 2 why I got the output like that?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[`BigDecimal.valueOf(double d)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#valueOf(double))  uses canonical `String` representation of double value, internally `Double.toString(double)` is used, that's why you are getting `0.9` in second case.

> **Note:** This is generally the preferred way to convert a double (or
>   float) into a BigDecimal, as the value returned is equal to that
>   resulting from constructing a BigDecimal from the result of using
>   `Double.toString(double)`.

While with [`new BigDecimal(0.9)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#BigDecimal(double)) it converts value to exact *floating point* representation of `double` value without using `String` representation,

> Translates a double into a `BigDecimal` which is the exact decimal
>   representation of the double's binary floating-point value.
>
> **...**
>
> **NOTES :**
>
> 1. The results of this constructor can be somewhat unpredictable.
>
> **...**

**FOR EXAMPLE :**

```
BigDecimal bd1 = new BigDecimal(Double.toString(0.9));
BigDecimal bd2 = new BigDecimal(0.9);
System.out.println(bd1);
System.out.println(bd2);
```

**OUTPUT :**

```
0.9
0.90000000000000002220446049250313080847263336181640625
```

Comment: Maybe worth to mention that the best way to initialize a `BigDecimal` is from a `String` or `char[]`. Once you have a `double` a rounding error has already been made. Converting back to a `String` may or may not undo that error. Mathematically, the exact double value is the better choice if you are concerned with accuracy.

Answer (score 3):

Just for those others that got here looking for some other issue with BigDecimal(not related to the question above)...
remember to give a mathContext to the methods to avoid certain problems e.g.

```
        MathContext mc = new MathContext(10, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
        BigDecimal hitRate = new BigDecimal(totalGetValuesHitted).divide(new BigDecimal(totalGetValuesRequested), mc);
        BigDecimal missRate = new BigDecimal(1.0, mc).subtract(hitRate, mc);
```